# Add-DistributionGroupMember - cannot find my group

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I'm using the following script:

```
import-csv "C:\users\USERNAME\desktop\dl.csv" | foreach {add-distributiongroupmember -id "My Group" -member $_.PrimarySMTPAddress}
```

However it returns:

Add-DistributionGroupMember: The operation could not be performed because 'My Group' could not be found.

How do I get it to find my group? I've confirmed it is connected to my domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

Does the group exists? Can you get it with:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Identity "My Group"
```

Comment: It can't find the group, but if I go into Active Directory Users and Computers I see it there. Maybe because it's in a certain OU?

Comment: Can you get it with the Get-Group cmdlet? If so, what's the group type? You might find that it is not a distribution group.

Comment: Yes, I can get it with the Get-Group cmdlet. I have confirmed that it is a distribution group. The error message I get when I use Get-DistributionGroup is "My Group is not a mail-enabled universal distribution group or security group."

Comment: To mail enable an existing universal group: Get-Group 'My Group' | Enable-DistributionGroup.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but I deleted the group and recreated it using Exchange Management Console and it works now.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue happened because the group was created as an "Office 365 group" You have to deleted and create it as a "Distribution Group".

I had the same problem creating a DL for external email on my office 365 server and trying to add member with powershell. Beside I choose to create a DL manually from the admin console it was created as an Office 365 group so make sure you have a DL. I delete the Office 365 group and create a DL and it worked perfect! Hope it help!